# How to complete this character table of GL(3,2)?

Tags: representation-theory

As is well-known, the second smallest non-abelian simple group is $G = \operatorname{GL}(3,2) \cong \operatorname{PSL(2,7)},$ which has order $168.$ (So elements of $G$ are $3 \times 3$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2.$) Using induction on the subgroup of matrices whose first column is $(1,0,0),$ which is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_4,$ I was able to compute the partial character table of $G$ to be
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & -1 & \frac{-4-\overline{c}}{1+2\overline{c}} & -1 - \frac{-4-\overline{c}}{1+2\overline{c}} & 1 & 0 \\
3 & -1 & c & -1 - c & 1 & 0 \\
6 & 2 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
7 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
8 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
for some complex number $c.$ I know that the answer is supposed to be $c = (-1+i\sqrt{7})/2,$ but I don't see how to conclude. It would be enough to show that $\Re{[c]} = -1/2,$ but I don't see how this follows from the orthogonality relations or anything else I know.